# Is it possible to get the table control from predefined pdf template using itext?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have predefined Report Template in pdf where I am adding some text-fields and table using LibreOffice. The text fields are retrieved using the following code  and data is populated successfully but I am unable to retrieve the table control using below code.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("Templatewithimage19.pdf");
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("test.pdf");
try {
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fileOutputStream);
    AcroFields form= stamper.getAcroFields();
    out.println(form.getFields());
    form.setField("payments_accounts", "$23654.23");
    stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
    stamper.close();
} catch (DocumentException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Your help in this regards will be highly appreciated.

Comment: please format your question.

Comment: code is formatted now

Comment: There's no table control in PDF.

Comment: But LibreOffice do have table control that can be added to pdf. Anyhow whats the way around for populating dynamic data in a table using itext without XFA forms.

Comment: Just like @Paulo said, there (usually) are no table controls in PDFs. When exporting the LO table controls to PDF, you essentially merely draw some lines or colored rectangles (for backgrounds) but forget the table entity.

Comment: @mkl is there a way to populate dynamic data in a predifned pdf template ?

Comment: If you want to populate PDF templates, the templates should contain form fields where you want to populate. If you don't want the final document to contain form fields, you can flatten the PDF after filling the form fields.

Comment: i don't wanna use xfa form and there is no such control as "table" other than that it seems impossible to use any control which is expandable to accommodate tabular data.

Comment: You can create a template for a table using a grid of AcroForm form fields (not an XFA form) as long as you have an idea how many cells of which size the table shall have.